# How do I debug D8 errors like "Type X is referenced as an interface from Y"?

Tags: android, gradle, android-d8

Right now I have a project that has 3 modules, one `app` module and a `streaming` module that uses its own `base` module.

When I build this project, it **always** fails in the `app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDev2Debug`, and it's **always** this:

> `AbortException: Type com.google.android.gms.internal.measurements.zz<something> is referenced as an interface from com.google.android.gms.internal.measurements.zz<something else>`

My `app` module's gradle looks like this:

```
...
ext {
    supportLibVersion = '28.0.0';
    gmsVersion = '15.0.0';
}

com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation files('libs/libadapterinmobi.jar')
    implementation project(':streaming')

    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.3.0'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.6@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation('com.redbricklane.zapr:zapr-sdk:3.2.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation 'com.redbricklane.zapr.admob:zapr-admob-adapter:2.1@aar'
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:palette-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibVersion"

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.4"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1"

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.1.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.4.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:17.1.0"

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:volley-integration:4.2.0@aar'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'

    implementation('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.30.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google'
    }
    implementation 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.22'
    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.9.8'
    implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.4.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.danikula:videocache:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.inmobi.monetization:inmobi-ads:7.2.1'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
    implementation 'com.github.livefront:bridge:v1.1.3'
    implementation 'frankiesardo:icepick:3.2.0'
    annotationProcessor 'frankiesardo:icepick-processor:3.2.0'
}
...
```

And my `streaming` module's gradle file looks like this:

```
...
androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}

com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //implementation files('libs/libadapterinmobi.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.1'


    implementation ("com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.28.0") {
        exclude group: 'com.google'
    }

    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.6@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.1.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:16.1.8'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.9.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-rtmp:2.9.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.9.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'

    implementation 'com.vinaysshenoy:mugen:1.0.2'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    implementation 'com.github.florent37:viewtooltip:1.1.6'

    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.2'

    implementation 'me.saket:better-link-movement-method:2.2.0'

    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'

    implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.2'

    implementation 'com.robinhood.ticker:ticker:2.0.1'

    implementation project(':playtrivia-base')
    //implementation project(':stepbarview')

    annotationProcessor "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    api "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
repositories {
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    mavenCentral()
}
...
```

Most of the posts regarding this error are found here and in github repos' issue pages, and all of them suggest excluding `com.google` in their gradle inclusion codes. The problem here is that I don't know which one to put that exclusion into, since I don't know which one uses `com.google.android.gms.internal.measurements.<something>`.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that all of the other solutions in those posts involve updating all the `Firebase` and `play-services` repos to their latest version. It doesn't work for me.

The project level `androidDependencies` Gradle task didn't help either (I had no hits when I searched for `internal`).

With all that, how do I even start debugging this?

Comment: Hi Gensoukyou1337, did you manage to fix your problem ? If yes what was it ?